# Dynamically create multiple WAF rules with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, amazon-waf

I've got a piece of Terraform code that creates a Web ACL with a set of rules in AWS.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "foo" {
    name        = "foo"
    description = "foo"
    scope       = "REGIONAL"
    default_action {
        block {}
    }
    rule {
      name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      priority = 0
      override_action {
        count {}
      }
      statement {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
          name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
          vendor_name = "AWS"
        }
      }
      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false 
        metric_name                 = "foo_name"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = false
      }
    }
    rule {
      name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      priority = 1
      override_action {
        count {}
      }
      statement {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
          name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
          vendor_name = "AWS"
        }
      }
      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
        metric_name                = "foo_name"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = false
      }
    }
    tags = {
      Tag1 = "Value1"
    }
    visibility_config {
      metric_name = "foo"
      sampled_requests_enabled = false
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    }   
}
```

This works fine, but adding more rules means that my code starts to turn into somewhat of a monolith.

Is there a way to create multiple rules in Terraform using `dynamic_blocks` or `for_each` or something else, in a way that looks cleaner and dry?

Comment: yes, the rules can be modelled using `dynamic` blocks. How specifically depends on what data, what part of the rule, you want to have variable

Comment: They're all going to have the exact config and follow the same format. name, priority, override_action, statement. etc. 
It's structuring it via dynamic_blocks that I'm struggling with.

Comment: You haven't demonstrated any dynamic blocks nor variables used in their creation. So its not clear what does it mean " structuring"? Any actual error messages or code samples?

Comment: you could use `for_each` - https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `dynamic` in combination with `for_each` like this:

Define a variable:

```
variable "rules" {
  type    = list
  default = [
    {
      name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      priority = 0
      managed_rule_group_statement_name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      priority = 1
      managed_rule_group_statement_name = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name = "foo_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then use it in the resource:

```
dynamic "rule" {
  for_each = toset(var.rules)

  content {
    name = rule.value.name
    priority = rule.value.priority
    override_action {
      count {}
    }
    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name = rule.value.managed_rule_group_statement_name
        vendor_name = rule.value.managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name
      }
    }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
      metric_name                = rule.value.metric_name
      sampled_requests_enabled   = false
    }
  }
}
```

(Note: Obviously this replaces your previous `rule` blocks. See also the documentation about [Dynamic Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) for more information.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the structure I was trying to construct.